# What is -s switch in if statement?

Tags: bash

What does -s switch do in if statement? E.g

```
if [ -s $File_name ]; then
   :
else
...
```

So what condition this -s switch checks?

Comment: `man test` or `man <your shell>` to find the info.

Comment: It seems that there is no man pages in AIX

Comment: There are (they're actually very complete on AIX). Maybe you haven't installed them though. And Google has all the man pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This flag tests if file with location `$File_name` exists and is not empty (size is greater than 0).

Answer (score 2):

`man test` says:

```
   -s FILE
          FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
```

Answer (score 1):

run `man [` in your shell and you will see:

```
   -s FILE
          FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://blog.linuxacademy.com/linux/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements/) (and the `man test` documentation), it checks if `$File_file` exists and has a size of more than 0 bytes.